# Java JComboBox and JButton

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton

I want to make a GUI like if user clicks on 6.A.M time in JComboBox and then Clicks on JButton then another window opens and picture of Desired route appers this is my condition but its not working like the command always goes on else block.. Please Help!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if("6.A.M.".equals((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())) {
          SixAMRoute sam=new SixAMRoute();
          sam.setVisible(true);
          this.dispose();
}
        else 
            System.out.print("Invalid");

}                                        

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //jButton1.setText((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    //jButton1.repaint();
}
```

Comment: what is the value from `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()`? because it clearly isn't `"6.A.M."`

Comment: its has different values like 12.A.M,3.P.M and also 6.A.M @Lino

Comment: add `System.out.print((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()));` to the else clause,  so that you can determine what the actual value is.

Comment: What are you populating the ComboBox with? Are they Strings or actual Dates? Debug or put traces as suggested to see what the actual value of `(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()` is. Apart from that, I suggest using constants for `"6.A.M."` and using it for both the comparison and populating the combo. That way you will avoid silly typing mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment: *its has different values like 12.A.M,3.P.M and also 6.A.M*. It seems like a typo in your `if` statement, because you have a trailing dot (`.`) at the end of the matching string:

```
---------v
if("6.A.M.".equals((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())){...}
```

Just remove the dot and it should work:

```
if("6.A.M".equals((String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem())){...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: @JohnSnow glad I could help. Though simple debugging your code could have helped you to get to the solution